# Disable selected dates in default Magento2 calendar

Tags: magento2, calendar

I have successfully added calender and disable previous Date in my custom form by using below code.

```
<script>
require([
    "jquery",
    "mage/calendar"
], function ($) {

    $("#My_ID").calendar({
        showsTime: false,
        hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
        buttonText: "<?php echo __('Select Date') ?>",
        minDate: new Date(),
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

How to disable List of dates which is in my database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can this code for disable dates

```
var disableddates = ["20-06-2016", "12-06-2016"]; // assign your database dates
function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
                    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
                    return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
                  }

                jQuery("#My_ID").calendar({
                        beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates
                    });
```

Comment: How to display only specific dates in calender?